# Check for Parent Child node in JSON using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am looking for JSON parsing reference, from where I can jump to question and check for Child question based on Yes section. I didn't find anything related to check for child node check in JSON. Angular is my base framework.

some use cases :

1. on load show Root question,
2. On selection  show next questions  which is child of root then go one
3. jump to number of questions from tree.

```
treeObj={
  "Root_Element": {
    "id": "myTree",
    "dt": {
      "choice": {
        "id": '0',
        "title": "Which color",
        "description": "Choose color ?",
        "choice": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Yellow",
            "description": "Yellow ? ,
            "choice": [
              {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "Dark Yellow",
                "description": "Dark Yellow ? 
              },
              {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "Light Yellow",
                "description": "Light Yellow ? 
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Red",
            "description": "Red ?"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Green",
            "description": "Green ?
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of levels in the JSON object is fixed and if it does not grow dynamically, you can use the ES6 destructuring to read the data from the nested JSON. Below is an example

```
var metadata = {
title: "Scratchpad",
translations: [
   {
    locale: "de",
    localization_tags: [ ],
    last_edit: "2014-04-14T08:43:37",
    url: "/de/docs/Tools/Scratchpad",
    title: "JavaScript-Umgebung"
   }
],
url: "/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad"
};

var { title: englishTitle, translations: [{ title: localeTitle }] } = metadata;

console.log(englishTitle); // "Scratchpad"
console.log(localeTitle);  // "JavaScript-Umgebung"
```

Comment: not this will grow , this is not fixed it may have multiple child and siblings up to N level